# Verifying sort order of Javascript array

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Table List contains many videocon items, many sony items, many LG items. I need to verify all items sorted based on LG, videocon, mitachi order or not?.

First videocon items should present. affter sony items, finally all LG items should present. I want to verify the order list.

Comment: Please consider re-wording your question. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Simple example: Air India Reservation system-> Evening you want to collect all bookings details, which booked today.  But here you need to verify all booking details sorted based on cleartrip, makemytrip, yatra order or not?  First cleartrip all booking details should be present, then makemytrip bookings, finally yatra booking should present or not? I need to verify this order list?

Comment: So each item in the array is also an array, and you want to sort these sub-arrays?

Comment: Yes. I want to verify, booking details sorted based the order-> first cleartrip all bookings, then makemytrip bookings. Just I want to verify the order.